# Tkinter: how to draw an image on a canvas with background

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use tkingter to make a card game.

1. set a table image as background of the canvas.
2. draw cards on top of the table background. This will be triggered by clicking a button (not shown here)

The problem is I can't create card image on top of table background. what's the right way to do it? do i need to create another canvas for card, in stead of directly drawing on table background? I feel there is something fundamental that i am missing here.

```
from tkinter import *
from PIL import Image, ImageTk


# globals
table_dir = "C:/Python36/resourse/table.png"
card_dir = "C:/Python36/resourse/card.jpg"

#CREATE APP
root = Tk()

#LOAD IMAGES
table_PIL = Image.open(table_dir)
table_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(table_PIL)
card_PIL = Image.open(card_dir)
card_image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(card_PIL)

#make canvas and set background image with a label
canv = Canvas(root, width=table_PIL.width, height=table_PIL.height, background="white")

background_label = Label(canv, image = table_image)
background_label.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1, relheight=1)
canv.grid(row=0, column=0)

#trying to create card image on top of background table, not working
canv.create_image(200, 100, image=card_image)

root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't use a label for the background. Use `canv.create_image(...)` to create the background, just like you do for creating cards.